# divs width based on screen width (with fixed div in between)

Tags: javascript, css, variables, html, width

Hi I am trying to make two divs to fill up the left and right side of my site, The content is a fixed width div (960 px) centered in the middle. I want the two outer divs to be banners with a clickable background image.

I searched, and found i could use CSS calc to do this, but it doesn't seem the best approach since it doesn't always work the same for all the browsers (like IE 11)

I think the best way is to do with Javascript, but I have no experience with that, can anyone help?

*[View my site](http://www.rollingstoned.nl)*

---

[image]
***<=*** *Left banner. Right banner.* ***=>***
[image]

---

(to get an idea about what it is I'm trying to do)

Many thanks in advance, I hope it's clear. English is not my native language

Comment: Make another floatable `<div></div>` one make `float:left` other `float:right` those who on left make `margin-right:widthofdiv;` and `margin-left:widthofdiv;` on right div!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need Javascript to do this.

I would create two elements with `position:absolute;` within your content and add `position:relative;` to the content `div`. Then push and pull them to the sides:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TnYfw/)**

(You will need to adjust the `width` and `height`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want since your question is a little bit confusing, and you don't specified if the images should be connected with the center div or with the browser borders, but I this fits your needs (please correct me if I'm wrong). I made it using CSS because there's no need to use javascript in this case, since this is a simple question and I think there's no compatibility issue.

**HTML:**

```
<img class="left" src="http://www.rollingstoned.nl/wp-content/themes/zine/images/leftbanner.png " />

<img class="right" src="http://www.rollingstoned.nl/wp-content/themes/zine/images/rightbanner.png" />

<div class="center"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin:0;
}
.right {
    position:absolute;

    left:50%;
    margin-left:40px; /* Half of .center width */

    height:100%;
}
.center {
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;

    height:100%;
    width:80px;

    left:50%;
    margin-left:-40px;

    background:#fff;
    box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.left {
    position:absolute;

    left:50%;
    margin-left:-374px; /* .right width + half of .center width */

    height:100%;
}
```

[**Updated JSFiddle Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/38XN8/1/)

Next time, please, provide an image demo of **what you want**, or a JSFiddle of what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about JSfiddle, the problem is you have the banners wrong in the example. The left banner should align against the middle (content) div with the white part on the outside. I tried with DonJuwe's method but i can't get it to work when i resize the window. If you rightclick at my site you can see i allready have the div's (leftbanner, rightbanner)with the background images set. You can adjust css if you use developer tools to see what i mean.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what I want to accomplish

http://www.rollingstoned.nl/wp-content/themes/zine/images/example.png

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/5ZhpC/

Alternative with fixed images:

http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/caRPV/

CSS:

```
*{
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
}
p {
    margin: 15px;
}
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    width   : 100%;
    margin  : 0 auto;
}
#center {
    position: absolute;
    width   : 300px;
    margin  : 0 auto;
    left    : 0;
    right   : 0;
    z-index : 1000;
    background :#fff;
}
#left,
#right {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width   : 50%;
    z-index : 1;
}
#left {
    float   : left;
}
#right {
    float   : right;
}
#left img {
    float : right;
    margin-right: 150px;
}
#right img {
    float : left;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
#left img,
#right img {
    width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
        <img src="http://www.rollingstoned.nl/wp-content/themes/zine/images/leftbanner.png "/>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <img src="http://www.rollingstoned.nl/wp-content/themes/zine/images/rightbanner.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        <p>
            Fruit is gezond, dat hoef je Carrie niet te vertellen. Om haar dagelijkse dosis vitamines wat op te leuken, stopt ze graag een extraatje in haar appel. De befaamde cannabis & appel combi dus, volgens ons een bijzonder gezonde manier om de dag mee te beginnen!
        </p><p>
        Fruit is gezond, dat hoef je Carrie niet te vertellen. Om haar dagelijkse dosis vitamines wat op te leuken, stopt ze graag een extraatje in haar appel. De befaamde cannabis & appel combi dus, volgens ons een bijzonder gezonde manier om de dag mee te beginnen!
        </p><p>
        Fruit is gezond, dat hoef je Carrie niet te vertellen. Om haar dagelijkse dosis vitamines wat op te leuken, stopt ze graag een extraatje in haar appel. De befaamde cannabis & appel combi dus, volgens ons een bijzonder gezonde manier om de dag mee te beginnen!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i figuered it out with the left:50% and margin-left:X px tags. It's working now. I also used the onclick="window.open('http://sensiseeds.com/nl/cannabis-zaden/buiten')" style="cursor: pointer;" property in my div tag, to get it to link in the right direction. Works like a charm!

Hav a look at my site to see it in action (there is a link in my question, I don't want to spam unnecessary).

Thanks a lot for the help, I would'nt have come to this without you guys ;-)